# A persistent conection is possible between wcf service and client

Tags: wcf

i was looking for a article to know that is it possible to open a persistent long connection open between service & client? one msdn article said not possible
**http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bd984f28-4458-4779-9dcd-dc79587711a4/wcf-service-and-force-time-out-after-certain-interval?forum=wcf**

the person is saying "Each time the WCF client makes a call to the WCF service, a connection must be opened between the two, credentials are given to the WCF service from the client, the service does its task, and the connection is closed between the client and the service. "

is it true? it is not possible to open persistent connection between service & client?
looking for some insight. thanks

Comment: What is the use case for keeping the connection open? Could this be solved with WebSockets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decorate your service class with these attributes to use a session based approach.

```
[InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession,
SessionMode=SessionMode.Allowed,
ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Single]
```

However, you will have to send a heartbeat request to your service to keep the session alive when idle every so often. This is not handled automatically.

Comment: one guy told me that when we call wcf then channel open and close after return data but here u r saying that if i use session then persistent connection will be possible. how do i know which one is right?

Comment: I had to go this route with a service a while back. A user would log in against a selected "system". The systems were different instances of a database on remote servers and other remote information including how to connect to other services running on the selected "system". I had to break a major tenant of SOA or go with the asmx approach and I chose the former. To make a long story short the backend "system" switching and repositories use DI and it was a hell of lot easier to have a persistent connection to a specific "system".

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning the system above works flawlessly but I new in advance the amount of concurrent users would be low enough to support a dedicated connection per user. I should point out that if you are going to have many, many concurrent users then there might be better alternatives.

Comment: You can also place a breakpoint on your services' constructor and see how many times it is hit when you app connects and request data. I am willing to bet the bank it's once.

Answer (score 1):

There are session based both way connections, witch keeps connection open, until timeout (if there is no activity from client).

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx for example.

But if it is not necessary for you to keep connection open, don't do it that way.